# Encrypting in NodeJs and Decrypting in Android

Tags: android, node.js, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

i am working on symmetric encryption, i have a nodeJs/express https server where i do my aes-256-cbc encryption with the following

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
const key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
 
exports.encrypt = (text,key,iv) => {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
        return { iv: iv.toString('hex'), encryptedData: encrypted.toString('hex') };
}
```

for development and testing purpose i send results as the following :

```
     const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
     const key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
     const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
     router.get('/xhtml', function(req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let xml_string = 
        fs.readFileSync("BookRessources/TheSilverChair/"+req.query.param1,"utf8");
        let encryptedData =encryptionSystem.encrypt(xml_string,key,iv)
        let keyString =Buffer.from(key, "base64").toString("hex")
        res.end(JSON.stringify({xml_string: 
        encryptedData.encryptedData,iv:encryptedData.iv,key:keyString}));
     res.end()
     });
```

In the client side on Andoird using Kotlin, i decrypt using :

```
// converting Hex String to ByteArray
fun String.decodeHex(): ByteArray {
    require(length % 2 == 0) { "Must have an even length" }

    return chunked(2)
            .map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }
            .toByteArray()
}
// Getting the Key from a String 
    private fun setKey(myKey: String):SecretKeySpec {
    var sha: MessageDigest? = null
    try {
        var key = myKey.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
        key = sha.digest(key)
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32)
        var secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
        return secretKey
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        throw e
    }
}
// Finally decrypting 
fun decrypt(cipherText: String, key: String, IV: String): String? {
    try {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding")
        val keySpec = setKey(key)
        val iv = IV.decodeHex()
        val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec)
        val text = cipherText.decodeHex()
        val decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(text)
        
        return String(decryptedText)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

Here is snippets for the key, iv and the encrypted data :

```
"xml_string": "b558282838947a21ea53595057ecf09e9697f91c41e9217a1672d17f5e2b26c55b833234ce55a1691b2d8d5f58097785550d9378331bc161f09c3fd4044643cdf7df8d778dbae2d593ccca830d5d8abf48431947cfc67cfa009aecb4326cc85772bb29a37d6fd19a9f7099185fcdf6879f1aea97f6b27552ed03399e45381f4122671f94b196ae2444ddb3ad812bc50bad3babdb47343555614db4ca68da7f9ae2b9b9c0dcfec51392a9d261ce6353b1cf78cd14b4688ce199c615b10ddae2da6f27de85fc74752c9437922eadbb6d712eee62fc9dc2fc491155d6a85dcf5a3e556ead1993c108864e6b5b4c5750977744c6d07ed13ce85522f05634e3f579474034b57ce9590e1c617bcedd9a06767ca2d7945dd3b26ce9e901aa8b4b8424ed4cabe93f3273fe4801ab0d499acbc7deb869b909df9e280c7b0bd0df522833eae16ebdea470b531d8fa354e09373078ee351526b585c8450937632e3c77a50543e006891b86282f5ed2bb6cf77ddf68f5470361ec3b99a6ef7a49e103afb370052922cc7f403cddc8b5995f87fc57533ee5d1d66acd5aceec071c21dc3a9e2ad3eda740c9f53712f3857ef4f28d40260949770ee65e25e6468ffe64f0cb7a4a21db4062aed8ceb23d1b2dd96b6182efbe23987567fc88f5992e84d89a269f3a945255e96e0b63f73d036890f341726926775c48ec3409692449f94e6beb4e2136551ab1e199912696c1287d047ad17e2744bcbc0a0b58dc402bfce85668e8095939bba1a722fbb38c8f192e243afcbb7983d4c359050a42861c823e46eb69ad65d99afefa568de8b9a7d0ce5efa3743030a354be5d61add4cc2872cd8cbabc3ab32caf3997ac89c84c454adc751c576d4dba339a7c00947ecdb40ad4dd0dd8009a24070fc9543a4812d2461dc1b010a2545647cafacd71c25beddfa67c59fd7172a4dc8a53011cd47a061db7fa6ab0b3094ff628a4bb6c5e5a6fea2341ab0d89d1cf9bfdc42bcee85ede9db9dcf0225447866645dccfa41e90ba242ceaf2ba709aeef14f59527170ce38ebe859ca835c7b920c275378dcb443ad2660b8652c72b0b4e80771811c1caf61a452226b579a33a417e0bee5aeadabef5de69a545c7e2b3f7d5f8ce0617c76bf98ca0d13cb669fe4e557bb8b76e19f5b56592d394468d8a1f86d09d3823b67ef8fde12740cff026cd612dced07cd4e06ba96ddc9cf9d3ee4ab74080bec144dc915fe61fae7bba78d6d4f6b63fc37c1dbaa542d71e55aee1896da978292449ff12d6393458def3e183ecceb50441bc7deb7106e44b58551175671b5c6535926cf7a4b41cbd3f3ec65a960c50b0cc20eb39a52ed9d189b35f3ea900d25168e4aa48c809e65576d6cb630789d17f36f80bb90acf5f5a7e06f2d5ba7a1897adfe972c7569cd12708556520471ad28b540ff8c1fb3b0b4d903c57b290e98d5a22236172c225737f37aef75789529954dc674208a7e67c9d7c64f0d1a73b8f8db5596a46370c90bc0532e3930d6ef3ca47d71926bcb5453a17774997807ccf68bdd7224176c2a19701ac5e2a6d31c43555f4daf1ce56b09c4d19d0ac8b2932dc9c6fb41a75278646300790a4fb9578925218e98463b8c8d7cd499246c55770b7ac3de5c19950b1b04111e9234ceb40527ac487f7910d6b9bb32fdc7347e02d69382fa81b6d62707af367858d6b116706f2fe632e4b16b49c9d0402ee8ac54b80b44c2ce2988269a0536063940c8ef38180f9b891b611002d7cb717e9ad9ca29caf6b259ee9da252275ef4cab23c64d2e7d52e67f6f5addd20b5079cbd7bf5dacb5f977bf4cb503ee3a1ce32053d588a2fe317e4ed833efade3a14c2e4c6b70175414f4eece4a15c51e34a55fa65d4e51909672b1335a25e6b3484b07085509ed5cf14294205ffec70ad04d9458ddc161b59c439debadc186470d5e76d5b00e5aebb1f4727321568a00618c5b875f74fcbafecbb77b589dab31ff7dab7165cb38d9e32e33a1d3177f259c609277ead087df44463daad729a37068101860aab44a80ca51eb22678a9197439e52b2ac2ca97dec15bc994664574fc560c49b33c32597f63ed96000589b264994096fc8d3fc40369e8c7624c423a307538f770adf589f89e84bf145b2e14d333176adaa4d71d04e5508ed2da8c2b20a22890f55885e93212172facff3812270ccb10cfb2b8789ad367ab23e6ec970e1bdfde32b6989567e078a913b09936e8fea92adfc77841141d53658397f9287498f23e19ffa11005544a7d46adaba0cf09f38767098a08736928013771e64f452c2e630af22d228ebf5d4c1d656773ea699644e3982563c0cfccd6241cb28d9f281b1935e780b13967d7c0e8cc786ecac03b0530e1f7eadb460a3e8e8a4af9f02ba5119e2e18278196857cac056315f0389697d102cb2177394bebbf947eaf0395f5274a3fae7e9b183961ae107d5750630bff9f79057e56657151ef1ab593d88104ef829c68e910fee5cf4e6335f82a94b65863f42f7a5a337206b09482c76937410ed3f87600e71448c6277c4cf546c70beedb3236c0c8c0b85294b4f3f838079bf879b6caf1cfff3faf60f7d27f7911f9c0dff026f2b39793711cc102948b6e64852786fba53216a344010470df5b2b121cd53bd35cbba4dd6d1192bffc7fe926b58e7125f4d3480475c5be34317d2cc98990de8804fc99812891a8f508873a56619c699028b5ab3efa7cb1e50d8ed321db4f7ad38cce53d99f133dbf01ebe496ac0cbaa8446b1329ad365ccbd822b01ae51d7ac1e9118bc24df0fa9aafd34b5999a66648b987ac1ce58ebb5bcb8fdb08b7d551a9e7018e9712e8047e57736545a64647c4748dee8927889448e65230144718418caa1aa063f0b1e75075f32dd0411dba1b2c0e0812f4234ba4bb6ba350042e70780f697be5e2421c6847abb19fc2db0b9b29414554e44e877f2975065e5b0f4759781bb95c9e12717d53fd68b5ba583071a3ad360de16f079ff7986e92412406bb58cbfdb604ffa35c919df1c847203ed16e0497d3a004af71d0c08e818b52260b7355e7b4b30506f47abc69fffce914f43983a8c34d3204cf77e864f1162b85986eda26fb53e6f74ddae922f5426febd627657d713fb9feb038dcf37031c0cba4addd1fbee228bc80192a88996ffd7d7a5cd05004f899a28044436526cf9ca49487e7cb2133f167cf09968a3d922511e241d993b2dd790137fe6dfd2717de73c3fb9d5666e393c6f656c537e398a21f67af3f5a3441651fea7ab1df1e87aba21303ebb5ec75b07e95dd1360e3452a9b166dd4477a5a0903dc890e65b8b64b1c6c49132b1fe5711695bf18263daed2232f2295f0eaed48ef2e2b3cd50dcddf95c5bb42564983336e31d9814c77a1ae05f4916816c791725b3128718740b835f016aa4ac3a716d279cbd712a6c6ff9d6eabfd7576641852f033ffc67b98e3c1761d8b1eaa89bee21cf918c8d102994d2b4c1bb9012ff0859166736c2809ccb1271a273f436f0d8c89c703f9c176dbafdd5b822312977051ff8e50eac9705f0ffda9f14585635242b295930d027833130cb3dcbebf4a7327e257d2c761d087d6e7a23efc76bba954ff9116f9f878257a534ee79b02dc75864d2dd616a2730653c783617734a73952b82a5804e9aa558a027fa4ec612ddbb48e54e95af273203e263570b02d0534b661d0cb366900afb7c173cb8c21b5fa34a8ed60c97c578b486f619deda7ac6c969cfc1633979b8c655270f1af3b97bf6d11f5f6b5a70b1109db7d1ce752bc26d87bb9779fa7961b7f4e35bc78a7b83bda8772f829d1d01bb0e523aafddd2b351676550388997fb9ee8a3ada1b27d0b786e41eb624215366d10f247d07433690373a10f61779d3c5819844f11d9abce4085b168d4063e4a21315586be8ff62c51046f3bd3394e68541977fd3728a5488bee1c8dec461d310c4b6cfb54841c310b9a6cf988fd63941ac21ee672a773fea2e9b8727aa709523898f5611c26dec9fdd30e3a80485e1c0fd7aa67456914e914aefa985005a9166cfd89dd1cc70d99bb0a1ce2f1603eb86905a0ac88256178f1c1f9db83677b1e023dbe5a667bf1a9d715f89b94b9b10fa4edf441f6f09523a3021eef23c56ba76f1840796da6889f886d57efc41a9e8e8d081c82d4252a02cf70afe00ebaa900c21271ae575acdebf130bef5635b3950cd1b72e1abc356431409d5bfa444ff451a314757a380f3acac15bf0fb1643ed5897ff0d1b872e8c503d274d7d9132441f2cbdd2e3f57ab9e5bbf0b9a944f9879bdd99b751cee48534f8c63abcf030194d22658902d968931422718697b696843e6ff343c895379fa0be3cb86598517c4e29f18450b8daf5d1f098061546244eba816b89c8d3f8e29c5baf3cce53f65fa406633e3fd47e11ec850e55f664975f53b9870a39b2716137e6340a61583f34067e7377804fe2b431a3f5dfcbc0a28ec3227679404226477846df5846ea1e9364bf857064e8eb036618ee6cd328d9876251d84ce45808b4bb9dcd8f030fb9bb7d6047360a5cad8d587a755cfbe03cae4c25e86024d315b7ad6c25a739123ea5852a1eb4636e1393dae7360953c62dce2ae0368a58287fd5857642f7e83db50415027a4ad93915db77b9b8eee8e67226a4dcea8d801b1356a42c92421d6864aac7208b75326e39096cab337891b81fb5963be3859796facf65b817ecd498c0fe39963a42e369bcd691ca940a490467acaadcc35dfd670df6db912a467ec9072d2e5044cd40b1ea7a49b938fbdd6f86474072b8351cf77c8fb1761fd3c477d0f2258953ff48000f44f7c326b4a7cc13591822315de5e02262678a59af5aacd326b4ee530132ff3b944b179c41f3417dcdc05c1c999553467594bf7282a5aed5af86d543ba69c1c2048aeda5f17221c4de12c0187c6ba58d8de7ff82d3b025b1ea35d63329056c8b16c44414ba57e84fdaae8594740bcad40d50294a6da760cb283c2224281e38dd8a58ada2e6bca94d655c8504a9aabea153b5d6088851081d33a06a0037b830b900cc4756625b4f55018f34674c00317070b07fe548c2f624a43fdf2c5ec071862871693e32a067dd3ffe8b6be0e9aa9b46e2f5314760679868a667afabc0284cef16637c3550649c027851f3e8bb495c1cd7d387e26834523bf974263a5eccfe334907e6bba48dcb4e6f68c0834ba52e3bc1e3c382cdb994452ea6d3d6ec2232f896d33959490aa2d0083ff7857b56b9d29e94cbf730e4775f022931d936dd478539f95ebee46760a8822cf0a38cb91f1dbfc991cad1305d1c507c89e45ed28ff375d4b6341c991f9ea0e4a5626e2229c4d4677744065fcb7044b5ac5e801571845975959ab162f7f3abf51d62a7421b707595372ea5b2ba387d1ca6aadabf4a630af2a002ededec51b7778c5cd88e1e7808d6063e461ff4623c73dc673ff1055432ccfb3f805ad37a139d022b3f6fa7dd6d6ac621ce2b94a9bfadecf8a1ed9ba12b2804b5beccb5d75cc71ec18f4ee0a69ec0e2eb110df4a46938c28a84cfd4a0dff6d8c14f1936eb750571140fa83fbc71b36d7df9f9789bb1b0684a6cf56eb5fc2195d4b028fd45726f33cd35ec1422d51d35a04ef9c4ead9827b6b067aa15f308a87b65dc7590b952dc447a05a82fc84033f28c713726263b3a1f40ef853393dcb970c4636689ee14cc90c30dbc180f1405507063245465dcdaf92d21411dcaa68b8a676b8da500e8f03581801585347529c1559952da61343c491a0bcf1ecf9d74b0bf001e2dd416bc741b380e668eda4ffb5067eeb8fa2f40bea06e7a64358e74fff8d047e2d78a21a7c6a2ee13c24a71b57444a767503dc8616bcd6bbce07c3b509c10301da8ba9001974434179945960cdbc77de4f8995a072989dfafc04489f72404a53730398aa73775fb62c70f164e671584a0d1c0a4d24c03e9233cb23b5b00d7f51eb13a6ecf0fd15d6ec9db401416eb9b31b8927c1960889f2e3b7c0c60c4ba4b39b4f1ab7dc68f366afd2f0a32c43ea7e22fc7bf48df076c3e2c006306b146c1f0785402602ede9ebba07d924e719ac05a138771b87367b45f3fdce04b0e4c77141dff2b367207afe5693c8840a1d5d08df2c2d464e2fdf60c0cb9d7ba2144c96a26aa72cf06f4cfd148481a153c4cd7f199818275755b59b46ea9bff6ef3a4443267272bd22269c1395784ead16b96074016180216a586c5b3fa19c6923e6df8c11436e84a4bdd5668aa9c5353ff0ceef9b1bdbb5de9ae3b1e066f3d3e2ef077ad8c44057097f175e26ed2353bb2b38dece3b08b602256b2cc06a3a8add3d5450fc0e035e695956097ed431fed6dc61f4df638cbea5c8351bb147a3659d1e96fc42469e09492c93ba5c3cf22474b34b2f8e70b46eef0851e5eb08d91d105f7585034660c11170254aeb38f95c0fa6b57b8269705e823ae0fd45fe31879816ae3ff671e53e82340d91533cf748d7c584533e164457fa34723bdfe658750a2cf697a6c45a6b39e25c87d1a72b9051e6b74539b74a353b0f4fdb1e9985205458ec400f710e531ded94cc565301abfd13810b290132d439e8438c5d936ae7d2a654270a35d76e9ebd8d2fcc28bfb7e81232e5425b87399dd96d581127140854e292de72d3b082db418c55bffa58ac633137e2a37bc2ce06083452ef6157af55dcb43ca90ed4b88c6f03ff812cbb66421c993cfd19e58c7b76398c3bdb86b46dacdc83e1582c4f66fea1f33e51e896d975bce9195cc1c74700d2bc15acb2eeb45e2602b22ef2ed34d685c4e5fb61b92292d51c0531a8f1d5a0ee00c9eec7703e280fe94353bdf1e206e119fe0afa5a528b2839b223408e45acc3f631ab9d49d8711cde4a2b5c9b4e7c3cefef8a101dfec433fa77ddd5183598f42dc9e96256b455e7aa2c1df07fb3d1ae7cb4b8418e2f65da69f076f90284db1fad3182abda21ac43f4ce6890c7cbb68f2aefe9f3928123ff2c20b1c08ec1c0a4fd3f548235fbe85e81f966938eb61926d5296549ca264e7b113986ee90f9c7a35d61f80d0331bd5ffff8543271f534702b25f08937135329e8ccd01b830456e2979f0471fd8df1f8574d4fc61983f433af2e3bf0cc944d418c45d3c68b01873370b63b7d817b10f0c455fc369d912168fef986430ff2a39c8f21851eca8ea77dee24dbaec44125fa5a78d1139a6ba02325c5fae4864b63da6fad75381f87eaef8655d923445877f6a9d87d80287ecde5e28e99e9ad70d951633055e66dbbb5451437f71b646243a9863fc7c5f6f45d319c46f2bca026a82ae9d30029a7630c4c95ad850bfd6a3f569d99a8fb332a8d68ff07648a895e0a454df38be6c9bfc680245334facd2897b1f01a326548c6397829afa979676434254185766372879f6baf29f9e7abee97402510f51ee5cfce98b9c8ee565533b96ae8f1e7f6a2898d8a97cca6a3a00b74023a91195e476a35e2d64b81b9f89512cbb2cc84088e48f8e754407b9c25b2b378a00a13195df9443a5f3ad0a379e436a712a8bfffc3dec824516062819f84edf3ddd3de4f1413567c72229ec9570d507a3dbbc870f1f9ca0df39170dea6f7665fa6aba58ec95f9b3f9a5f43755378ccf07d0a3b5938174e166a5cdaa02d5a43991d035423c628ba9bf509b5baff896f940af8bca1b82eaf2f196dc9e626ec31748de1285b77e4548cd25a48e4ef8e5694855e1ee529f7969b074840a54c3bbcb188bbba9950306974560f462c4e939c5b8d7684a8ac5ca641910682c455e5733c2d46b8c466aa31edcb1d1e0ec39e8324f2faf238828ec3a883fe45d13bb2272a67dd0f83eddad30be032bbc2b1a96bd26b8f9bd8a7e932a3d4665d8cd6b7e0ad9a78bf8ed4e6d2b530fa950b71807bbdde2508b1373879b972fb31732bfdd2d28459c4f76a84ade85dc2bcc84d29e9880aeed4654ec1fcb7200121c8786828dcb7efc26626d6bd52493600f8be8c02cdf6e23f7ef91860573d3c62e638112761d2988af90985d6b18b32742fefef47b46c452b0354a99a3c692f16961dfc5674bd8f975c8991b93684ed335cd034f0f039e98da6632dcd0c3eef4b7082756fcb76832ecdf242e80332df5aad9f4ef6b6ec58cade495710c7c6f1aeedf0cd66426cc2bed3e85eeaad60da1a83de5269f2aa31101bc9c5e820aca2ac2bdcc6baec9b5ea02aa175a767ded8752752b5b57fa955ce364f4454988be873d1f1432f9981d67a7c4da81da54fed4052e68081fda4748513041b274adc99db81ca95128c712ae484391a46e1139c32f5fa6c4211576aa2faf1d937068567a4c915fe75b405b5bf6b1f21ae007a7755a6f6edbd1d871b87a16ccbafa26397f346daa092b7359cb9573a1c3ee839207f298818cb0a27aaee7db16350c6bc8a2108f884fb1b3d62a8df7e03ae11f910cf6e53fc7c1f9c22145165afdd86bd1846abd0e6bb46b4a0f1b6af9bf953da77c6ec383a36269b213131e7e906723e6c8a2de23c2b01d82fe30f3f932c14b29bbc3f3bcd9b725981ee24cc5a04e519083f72ae47698f54cd5a915740a18b8119e86b4a1db92795d526a86c284de06160087a247f361db04bc370486ddad06f641e60b67c6a2ad6b2bbad58f9921c82622c716ec2ab55c2d77998382bba3b69464e47228763302d86a2b9274412ab5b6a99dadf04c7e1615916cd9e30457c69780b6aaae520119832142c79005101bc1471b52bba6d3b5112effe02e5b140210f57133bb7808c5f44d07987817ee4edfb14d8785179f3acf2430f8e8033bd5056b98e3aa75910cda3c54368d2d36f45224bfb40658ad878fe9b0b225e3ba646ce8c86ab807e074644ffb22c34373ee29d46b9c0deadfba426e41b10ea018d06aaf0c5446472551bcdf8780252783b0aff190d3cbbe7f108b8eb6aba331b0482ae9f018b37e1ce137acfdc15aca77af61e1644d73549de905ef903edff2fdb67218f74df09550a41a97ab7fe2fa5ffeb463e9bd0cbb3ef961714cf5a3cf081db82fa152db73fbf1aeb7095a06c2cf7ee4a625396dbae8864b7a63aca9c5b2e5d132633d9e681b7cb2f93b7f2e2b42e5e5f347cb14bc48265f5595e7e20855bb4318785f6bc5be93e42b99cfbf3dd0b1fcfa716f9f07da275599f319ebabb907de4942461c676fb15ac3c0054a97ab37234b928e0651c980671530a80e21c4fecd92ac4378a7958a0cb8cd9f6fb8d79993527ce7791671ff05b1b4fd63182b77adf49e2c205e2d5fc6b8dd5163dbbbfbc5aff4f150d6066ecc59a22162f67ad98c8deaff53ba53039f647bd07f4460c71b601ac6f54bdece7be34befba57119197a0aa0fc167e14fc753e0c350a671bfd469542ee419654ff966523438ee28f8b2d09744a088550078e5be63d529b44a4995bc8ab03b39d6cdf476c36dc4a4f969c3d125f27146a446a5d2cc12dbcdb62ff30415eba05cdaf2865bb67eaa9b9061b0468fbdddcbe9aa227e23ea8c45eab131e69ef1f00880696bd5e40bca4693d1ee1bb864e393cf28de49fc3b45e8393d156c03da0b9f2360f27f8a9963a4602a09f5d55107fb2e0b062142e992f92ddee870293bf0faf3a4ddcdfbee653a0cf2d53a53f66f46130b341f8afab5d615710b5b5d8128269a4eec3d30aee252ffbbc2052ea1ff6ce60f79f8194d295fc79d4fabae62485716475b10f0495ec3b8c639d560ce8b99b29005940b0477ecf3d15a67e4b1458dfd99d6cf673a3584aad2d2930c13b3fc48a0528098d751dbb2cafe5cd63d709a59e342480102fd4d5d4e026834b961d6f8baf317e00eec31136f38ee7cfa4601816773288ac3506d0f4d7b301a9cf2d5ae7f4ab114f34a721894f8860701b6f046f42d4e0cf24be79f09a1c2dcd430e8d4f7a87411c8f25e54b6fa8ff0087bf873c8f63aa134ea3b42e9a90c5b3103d423c564216a4b9d7f0d8024d0c53be35289304cde6c40f3d2871dfb852eb0cf9f04792e38620462419d6a2cafba2a12dd6b10a06cdf0b321c1f233489881121aeff4a6dedc06e8cec26e35d4e1585b05b7b5af371766596057ea31b5303d9c90fd25739224b6025be938e475c6d56f31f1d391e21b0127bd4b023f633fb25e3431f50a0963f1a9e3499c607d2825495cccec8767d6090890a8cf4c7752fb9d8e25961de95d68a1f548bc628c2b3a761d351f162f4cc99fc3c4bc58688daef804787ad45b8fff2a7975c76f28b57003220ed237d3d2a43ebe72d5bbd914a4452ccbff1a4f3c97ab8ff63e69983acea9da31c5c1dd25866fa533d390af9c7d3e5d5084c7e0b359508d2fce6bbbfc9e36f8be49c66e4bf86a79053aa224b8178d59eefc714bf5eeb423aa0645a0eb0c859c4a0a289ebd4773b46367cbc0c829f998c8f4b89db29a3454c97a438d591a9b5fd87fc126fbf279a0f41fe491920ae895bf04b447ee0d8397ad08b3e7e31c8bf31ffa05e396aa41ac63c03b6e4e5acf0cde5f53ca6ec116f5114305283975eb222bee93bd8aa173d346a1f827b798afd8f7df8609090ccacacb81b9cd351a017d988ecda59d503b216edaabb5ec895941707ee300de6311e1d62c8cfe9ce6f5276a521908c604470ffc0c7548a79ebedd315f8772eef87e0cb154f5c82c99c584ea28039a0cebaeb1318ef99b3d086c9ea69fdc398cecc346a0f000858f19fe18afbd232c6753c0430e51cfc65681724c1ea3ac80c93636e644b996594f4a98b5eb596e3d69e5ccd87d25cd287f3f55f0e12b9a38340db62cad4fa3e8ddcd940868576270137f96d3884837bcd8e2246046d64e35a2ee9c0fca0b7ade9e0b0c6f5cc1e31e9f38b1993882f8c8263b834f51e5a64da820f08baf324b661714425f26febe2bf53e3738707fc9c38a91b77acfecc7779c7744ae072ce34ba2ac8cc7399454cc7ebb279d0b952f5aad516011831774c4803f608329aae63349a59c19475b540f3e41156d56bcb1eb6afaeab1e062a68151708599ca6b9d076de284c8175a945f43b0a748d3a4220482befd2a688a5f8d278f176a800fcf82488c31b1ddee28af207ad18c188d169177b111a49280e9811cc52f07f9864e658c3abb0e3df463b44a262bfd21c75029a73b643194acfa2abaa5085b68e99a06a4fb71682f29755e8f9d91af12b150dfb7d9bc71ea01a94d72f664a756d1540025462a156618a71fa58cc256c2bcf0fa9954be618bb456ea9ad9bcfc09ed6a383aa5677a7f9b2e81669271e979bc6584330ed49f0eeb0a6169d17a0588e5e79ab463bde03539a3897a462cdfd8cdf56b41d3747f0d8ecb407e506b73860c60ef8b6b678984b79cf9189c28ab1e66cfa77b7021195d22fe4263e725a80b5578574951841ea855b5f8cfa04b434ea5b83b136715271f57645cb442d0f4ff2c3881037f63778debab67234d677e435ddfd390592a474eaa95fe06a721808619f2db3cd1616d8785c3b3cf3dc1c52be073a241ef0f3b8a3ccba624bb22ee92b75e2056f212658b4537891724f5828362eb6a47c5ff23d969bda71ea1999ebdf12ec440f9c8e02a61c8a60521a3677f4de1526913de8e266a83457f76bcd600c9c315186745c0b61ece77dece104178ad1686a42f4b5639d59840708ae064cf4d993fca2e092957b6f03a116bb01ac9e403e185308d2566012669cea2017bf3996971c05d26b561995ab57abaeebfe16169f6e4212780377b165c113a3a453f092260577bd9c61bf11d57b3a2c049b05ae37a03d4eed5a8c258d30b5affc36e88bf68bb89cb46a4ca57180279f745b4fde9be5728c559e0f6d2a25945b310655263fba0d3ba723c45a9607f2daac915de3d493cc51ef3f10352a32d753b57d89bf7089f8bd5015446bee237f0e0fb33b9278e27b65fbbd6f95be5f29c0d6dc0261b34f775dac394d5fcf12c4ed9fbfd8ac24220388e2e2aa91b394fe33e15c54fe71276d40a75ec7f696903931c2f41e4df6799c0cb4d3854e1acac3d65e45ecf6e43152cd369ba0913e07ac83b5dd6846a6feeafc1467793908f47b248dc4f3dd6d7e641941d26f50edd1eaf7a1f6f8eef0cf3afacb8c27228ad2de55bb50b018c4a616418a74cb3a768dc4423e9de1131dfd32d6bddc0f4a5d388dd335e149b8026f4026bdb976bd2886df421e2c5c1638d3219fb5ee767b950480752b63d4e6e6d3dad1388fb8c2f2458ffc09b1290dd76af4fd84a3c8e993060569f3c0c18d16271818ab155117e14ae35eea3c1801e5267e248d328a6999942926b8d10751c0d413f2a02894b154027494340c60d2bd84aa41e8a6e2224504b53127c6131c4c5babcbe8cbe28f55aa7374ddd397ab72dce3f8dac5d387af286909f915cd9544ba3a1dfcc0cea980aef0c340be2fc95f5e3163a598707947dc24bfabc62f44ffa2fe475d402d065ab8b21f94543f1f45ef49ebb5b2a2a186f12945b373de95d4034cd63eda0662e4405c50159f4fe3b0f97e72abbe18e710d7a34b6e8b8a0a2ffd861cc62032239b69abb4243b48f8d9f03aecc1713a5cc603157f77baf1fc7c0a17b639fa7ac09fc4780fd99dce54222c4243b438b2df4c6571fb028559f8dda2e85b451a0842a9b76e074b8805e0bfb18164b18f6999b9212160c013349b3b7df2eaf9d7e4e57c053f097b66455e941951d4437e3591185d81f69ee26af88a6f4c87f71aef01394813b35f59f23733abf858c24cf8dcc6ca1653dc759b691c65b5b1017d1424e014879977e2407963632e7c016a5c1eadd64430370d4e1e519b94b4801e0465f9452774e1cebd842cd965d3ea6f60b09f3349870405e6b1b18b5abccb04f95c75ef0b3915010a2ae1d7be4c9d14b73ee987cd06f283464291c5cad6450c4d0325ede71edf7c5b6a59b89d6f6f6722e7c72704e7dc817d9ba5c5319d49a0e9cad1e16172b3e34d0801a91c644698aec0d0232df7c1c3a0ef08ffdde0e9c9285c93fae69b6dce801195e4288ca2f040efb3634ee6c49e379a3e492b453bacb84328f8cac21fb59dd0e946e54c0ac25fe883e9b1412e330f580e9d425bda2ef94cca8154cc28323bfbae2450c31868f3ea114f95c544788270714fe8d954fb00e2e2ed97d2400ecb681823e68f8226366ec0648a96cbb696a3c248b1eb4d6b98ccf9484d2b180cf4ac2a4051ed33f2d0b6dc2a80efc73eea7ec28a97f9470994076f0e322288e6842c3ad44b160d5aa1d1f266f406d5b477c26a53f55f3d81ada919b181ef1e5645974d971c0c225262b27a1ead1558843957c662eceaaf0f1e5d9dccff188ea6228636284cddf17dc14d2b9bf9d9d52de357ae6521055b45f9b845245ca9166b66f5d197cf5f17310ad15d9bb03249dc17c184b6e6b6a96b158850809535ac6ec730ea788afa3d21d16e358d9d5b494b2710e8b9c239759943fcc6855f28267b0945a9f74829f9c73074572f94d96c3363cd241b65568c2a5107c9f0fbf45676509a365d2580aac33827f03239b91526d785830e794afef8c50c45f3a5b08446264bd652ba9384142127793fd3304cd918323e97e328c35318dc45666bff5268d0c89fcf83de830f9e75ba4374d772bf5163afc76258386c37621a49f9427b4de1b1bbc33c76b0702929236ce27406ae5d0908dd23612cbd5ef2a58532bdc69fe3a932857d7662a737ca4f341ae45685e3df55e1f71be743222f5f882201dd27b9fdbc198508c7719fce60f582c34f16487f68fbce5b9fe33bedb86fdb7b233de7934d1f81a4041de830c3ca8dfcfbf2251539f21d48386ddcc1d2de34a5ed4e80ecd2799d14468c4460807c07e9f9edf200f98c55523b63338dc9c4a1cc6d01bdf1cfe1a07e4315adf34f95d9110d70a984a937a0e9861d0f73418c0eba88df5605a54879382858e55cd4df995f6333659722f46ec8266baa65b20eb5eeaf0bd0fd7bb26c1ffd6850d0e2aa40462677d829e798b29a83de87ee4c90655ceb7c249c237e02a3fb1444d25a9403b75f5003f6ce4d9b9b39880744dbcafbb410922d47f8981057ddb48cc7791ef11e87cea39297b8057ac230c8fc433611b8975556432d46a534bff9eacff6b42a0eb17d933f76d1c069150dbb5a33d6e4aef414c824fb0f06a8f7abfde2e3400972064b3cb7ccebec5b7a6545fcdc62ad07f0fea11d59da1418e0c07b0d9fb111e058330fc91cad9ac1a3911f0308dcc6a7238b91de66a25680bebc23ccf7f92286f75ef005276f159ae4c21a1a7f6347b94f714b37fa673d78849c0b42853a8dc562fbd68cb73eb0dff62e74dabe06f7b44b64ec77baeb9a364a4f42e7b36179c266e621e8f9982e22e9645a4eebd1fa3c4ba5edccd949782bd67bd4aa6b2fb45b9d20e0ac5d0343cbbcf9f532b86dd0d2002dd2a397d3e067f537411703085fff3d25f850b802ddb7c82a8741c530ec3680b2e3d40eca2e0cfd0d0913c978e3d1136ea2ec3d2615431281c0ff81fcd000fc6aa3675ace0a773ed2010b2ab20fabcdabad124102b6f6b58cd92d264e7b1f410298948fed4200fd8d4f846bad5a6869e07660ceb1c357b68f6cba96d34e1c501fbb4ea9cd764e0ecbcff20e4dff51ef87cdf2bb636257a8dbe6e243a06f71ed8e048608f2bf536eb2094990b12b7facd5268c8c78e99abd5100314e413315d19e1b5c3cd914a4c1e07f474f3a759a892530d12f33737c60c35a6a7ff05b85e1122a6496d1d144bdb2e0f656bcd9b52c373f3aa91d1cb06f4f22853da7d4244ba7361f6a88a50ea1bb1de17cb7e4dab451f6065d78516de9056af535248381825d1ed119319ea305668f8ea73b3a162c4532d0dec8e2e6a185e5ca08bb61ee6975d06b8283a02a2472cb44f67e8c7bb18ec5317677fecf6731c6498192dd28105f4b0a21287d81e6f823d3ecc737688a6bce5c5fbba93adbf3a49928a4cc5724b98fc0c79ef5de5e994f6171e977e3d6d43a66712afa1b46375b0689be1e974f1e3a7e4696879e9c7a6e5db5c7c44ad4319f88e12e49727082d8a3ed25c5ae5b27fc9267fcee3733bb301b7b8728f9ce5f5ba91b1bcebd65157d6970f8a07850c78a940466a51ae31a1e9521f4aa26669af14be91b3c6c78d4fb0d89388cbbeb225a757778ff043edebb4d378cbf435f7bcbaee28fd63e1b96e8d454c71c9602982e3dccedaa3f2e4855de688850e36afef0882def68e9c6a518a4d2a43d77ad3a778c1d6f051be2889441fabce6f60c6076745ee74b2a827670078f33506112b0700b707a16d32c1cbea3d5ab3021ad8379703984224241f5b61b9221cf4c35361c1dc5d7e0ed504dce0ebe04bc7a899b79e06f6584e0f1f6e40a535d7b33aad620d6ebe517122a01c7e69fe6cc8f0c203516bc5761cfb57516a37f66b894f64438903540f7808994d5f2b3814826f185d96b8b12df134d313457bb02889622e0d0ed75cf0cbc7ee62dd1a24e8fae18b30bd4309a1c06191139e2bf8490f1287a521df945df19e5f48ddf440f0d99159177e784af1ce4208a93afe307cb7ad58cf671050d4b8324781869795205759e9210897d9185eeaf55e07ddcb1b5d3a279a77a1f2fc7a47efdec9063ba9951277d5e8bf9e6d26de5bf41be350c32c43860209f6daa92847a4288e60eed029728fac833577b5af905e78dc6c4a449b07c7a2a3937f5c305250d35cf94b8175f0acf286959088f88daaa978be8e974345027a0b0908be397ea945374f177b580260828542ccb78328024f6afca6cbc5ff0c89e2a13d06c93ebceb5b173aeb5d59f2d2cebea3e8572c6743fdef96eb056ddfe57f3550e2add365e6e223ddb40b147018bcd582d585cdb136b02bde41b258044fe2332a7898cc1b44444eebf2cec76fe494d2a96275a950b8dca42568bd9b54d3385877d9ecf1d4ae978c05ba1db802be3ee64c8c34cf940d0629118220abe3d1a3ca189ae4eb44a080f81d564336c71a365134bf64932eda38ac624b8f3234b61bd995fd3998f937304e9b4753e7c9bfd643c890b0359cbbfb497e5cbe291010d75d32e170ba676740aca0b2bdbb298c0707924f1ca93a2ddcc66d41f4f283ecb2953ec7e784a17d66e329869cff3f6604aa00e38211af1ef2cd98c88175dcc78e1cc43c4b1a02775000641b723d0f42e8f10e47eac75bb856049beb70bc5d7563bceb7dfc4806eaf95c483990181bb43a67d9175749e139413dc446977377d4345cd469f7903dba4befb4786fa2d4cc2f882f40f4cdf3570f32b72fff170b3852460a7e71ecc37182ab98c5dcaf4cd3aa0ddcc986abd8d0dd7f08db90a7ad4f497f484bf6ed7288dc2b929aeb4cae910a448638f1670908fba915d4ece079421e6a8d39a2a43873dbcc577bd257c2488344ab19de7b0f37f3662b2e65ae685b201c01753880559611448191041b6ccae985ed58fa0c1b5df4bddd62b9ae97bb6f15b6d77cc4ac95ccdb8bd648202164e63e549d067e28313a103e53a762ca52b3b55fcbbad1da1a4a00520de9931dff4a7750b507f31deb1fa0e528d85fde3c2f6c35aa888b0fc52f24f028a7ada347b97c3df0820caf039e45f3f3e01816caeb2187914fa08e75314a74f2e8bca93dce7a0b833ce4b5d047291054d54c00ef44e3c8a9b2ac26be217ab86f9cf5e2889af24c4761c5aa2a203bc37b41da24e18b9ffdc2cad0e3ec9c5a2d6c7525633aca5818d482b6378568e791d67301280fc7befa609425166a8917de88c5712f23967601219559d0b1748514c0bf3abeb6583b05a44676f8f3d584bde5e452a7eafe4ff56bb3815fd9b68ce2e4bd8dea419569b98924bfa9bdb16114d0b5a0c92741e6b2cf9ec1fc97b97640b5b40090f77e795feab78c15d0d0cdeff736c6fd1f9b83e3eef3b96eb476eba2c872782a4af6ee8477a5ffd7ed99245fb5b936ea5168d9e3d4e9d327e3b97f3a26587f1329f73ec3f59a7b6a22e116641d26e5e5299dec6d8dd7fc673f88754cd042c0e3cad8349e9dc3f1861eefd425f9206772d38e66a28056541da48e5f930d053358fe8921ce13a7b1725d65ed7b642ec7d8366ee9cf210e43d6e104afca934393f3d18e41a94c4707abd38673065628a0467a2bfd201a1c4f2c7ea8a61ce0882856a50e1a6be7dfd3925221f71029d8f3297dbecc7929a8515fc75cddd8fa067d8c5e60920fb9a18c841813f2c12d60401cb28325f960ac87b6d8cf189fbbfa6ebcd74750e71d8cf19c020fb40a51b5672c1292664f3a31abb4bae8cdc8ea5b8ae586be3d961b30e4b2c5bb4d52ae8903133db96d264ae6db03f2acb81f5e87fec04a42d8000d43c1d087227e5db6dfd351b3ca90e3292801c3f3058c70d536df6935be143009b5a559acf163eb3f5d86e870098cdb395d00c247fb7b0cf757142f6aa6ed54302e9c9ee088f35a40be49fe754695e30fd470e19b61cf25b4fa3e7ed4fde7d84c8199707accd7fd2a8ece077c26b2a1bb96595199827521a775618d7ef86ef0a8b70b55c44984eca2f96f7386d5898002ac95d019048ae2f1a9b0debbb9732514c121d2099d440bee55e945cd74cf085154fda6aa65d760a673315123a0d2a72b3777d8ebfce4608b6b4b812a04520abeae5a18a7cfa1055c0852435e6646e5f827fc7e3a7cd3c99f9d7e8baadf573428b9780ce0fcd709ea4e9e1406f1785bc10b984b80a0d8e46b1c55d1bf37987fe49f7dae4a9ca2e4c2186b1d31f4b869e29e6251b8ef743ab3b3ec2934584b95690bc76a839e5a1f324daaedaa3866a44ff8eea51214c66c5f6b8e281805535df924e241c8c05a209c6543c187cb00a9989963ab46a83ce0f7d3be888837153843dd709b39f515e5fb97ba3c9784bcbed9f9e0bfa3f799ce910d7b0ad07b6ffaaeabb34becaf00ab00b1854400193953b74c228664eee7fc6712aaf0ff927168565faff3628d0abf324ff40c7ec39085f76122175d74e38e5d07b04b1dba30d3dca315130f5b5700df5116e13c76ee65e4912e7559b53e07b8dda6b1ec6cf9373fb14cc50ffb648c81d776acd03b028e6161abe227ca9b41e65dfde2ed75ed82cf1ef439d6fefd210a6de2dc29083227932e0531fa150db0e434da413a43142ed244afc1e6e26eb271d54326d1c736538d68363a9782d8e3f16a0b36e0a7c107eb0e233eb1db54ce54a55cd97cc4742e64b95fdabd34f6c53758f672787943e50a95d7738dae260d04c06fb21752f9e6bf2b16ee3f3a9cab13026141021f8008cf389d5425fe86e7d93ad45c736043577f97636d827810f93bd2c5ff77b96c22ab4b4c335d80fab8e40fe85693057414e8e8a1f5b893c2ae5154550840a904a134c9cd77b8501bc59fa79c2fc19ddd3d",
"iv": "bce8e1e081ee4def6001ddaccd3afecc",
"key": "8e1e7e7cc9ff2457deda3fb012b1ec65a042cd08e1264f83a706bc5fdf12a562"
```

The decrypted text is not clear, it gives me something like this

```
���\��n%�Вl��v+\"�I���l�+��R�_�}��`}��g���ӄ�_Pr�������D���A�[�*�
```

thanks for helping, mention me if something is unclear.

Comment: I have to mention that i tried to decode the key the same i do with the IV (decodeHex) but same results, also i changed from AES/CBC/NoPadding to different padding (in case the crypto module in NodeJs uses some padding) but it gives me a padding exception

Comment: I tried not hashing the key (setKey()) same result, for the PKCSC5Padding it results to a padding exception.

Comment: The exampls is the ouput omt nodeJs, but why its not decryptable with AES-CBC if it is encrypted with aes-256-cbc ?

Comment: The decryption is done on the side of nodeJs, how can know if the data i get after encryption is valid ? If the decryption succed. The lenght of the data i am trying to encrypt is long, what do you suggest for an other encryption ?

Comment: @Topaco i solved the problem, i will post it, thanks for helping !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was the conversion of hex String to bytes, the iv string, the encrypted CipherText as well as the key string weren't converted properly to bytes.
In addition to the PKCS5Padding that must be applied in the Kotlin code.
here is the functions used to get the original key and iv of encryption :

```
fun toByte(hexString: String): ByteArray? {
    val len = hexString.length / 2
    val result = ByteArray(len)
    for (i in 0 until len) result[i] = 
    Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).toByte()
    return result
}

fun setKey(myKey: String):SecretKeySpec {
    try {
        var key = toByte(myKey)
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32)
        var secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
        return secretKey
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        throw e
    }
}

//finally Decryption 

fun decrypt(cipherText: String, key: String, IV: String): String? {
    try {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        val keySpec = setKey(key)
        val iv = toByte(IV)
        val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec)
        val text = toByte(cipherText)
        val decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(text)

        return String(decryptedText)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

For the NodeJs server, everything stay the same.